# OptaPlanner/TimeFold FULL_ASSERT vs NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

I understand that `FULL_ASSERT` can call `calculateScore()` multiple times whereas `NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT` won't. Given that, why would I ever want to use `FULL_ASSERT`? Does it do more checking than `NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT`? Is it faster? The documentation doesn't make this clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FULL_ASSERT` does more checks than `NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT`. In particular, it does both the intrusive `FAST_ASSERT` checks and the non-intrusive `NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT` checks. `NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT` does not do the intrusive `FAST_ASSERT` checks, because (as the name imply), all the checks it does are non-intrusive.

As for what intrusive checks are, they check for variable listener corruption and score corruption, which require calculating the score multiple times (for instance, in FAST_ASSERT/FULL_ASSERT, it checks if the score after a undo move the same as the score before the move, which is assumed true in non-intrusive modes).